# ELMAH : Include POST request parameters in error report

Tags: http, post, elmah

I want POST parameters passed in the request to be included in the error report.

Comment: If you want JSON see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686466/elmah-how-to-get-json-http-request-body-from-error-report/8741276#8741276

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out that form parameters are available in the XML report, and not shown in the detailed view to avoid cluttering the page.

Comment: When I view the Raw/Source data in XML I don't see post values. Where are you finding them?

Comment: Same here, cant find the post params even in the raw XML. Any clues if I need to turn on some setting or som thing else?

Comment: ditto, I'm storing the data in the database and not as xml files. Maybe thats the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got the XML report.

Open Elmah (e.g. http://myapp.com/elmah.axd)

Click on Download Log (on the gray menu at the top of the page).
The browser will prompt you the save a CSV file.

Open the CSV file in Excel.

Look for the column XMLREF

Use the URL to get the XML report for the page you are interested in.