# ELMAH - How to log HTTP request body and HTTP request header with error log?

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, elmah, error-logging, openrasta

I'm logging errors by specifically signalling errors

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
```

How do I add request body and headers in the errors details. I'm just using the email feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend sent me [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8741276/148271) which resolved my problem.